# Photo gallery not open in titanium 1.0

Tags: javascript, photo-gallery

I am developing new app. using titanium 1.0 In that I am opening phtogallery in new window but I am not able to open it why this was happened?

Code to open photogallery in app.js

Titanium.App.addEventListener('recordvideo', function(e)
{
    win1.close();

```
var w = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
```

backgroundColor:'#336699',
  title:'Modal Window',
  barColor:'black',
  url:'xhr_testfileupload.js'
 });

```
w.open({animated:true});
```

});

xhr_testfileupload.js code:

var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var ind=Titanium.UI.createProgressBar({
 width:200,
 height:50,
 min:0,
 max:1,
 value:0,
 style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN,
 top:10,
 message:'Uploading Image',
 font:{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'},
 color:'#888'
});

win.add(ind);
ind.show();

Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({

success:function(event)
 {
  Ti.API.info("success! event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
  var image = event.media;

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onerror = function(e)
  {
   Ti.API.info('IN ERROR ' + e.error);
  };
  xhr.onload = function()
  {
   Ti.API.info('IN ONLOAD ' + this.status + ' readyState ' + this.readyState);
  };
  xhr.onsendstream = function(e)
  {
   ind.value = e.progress ;
   Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress);
  }
  // open the client
  xhr.open('POST','https://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost');

// send the data
  xhr.send({media:image,username:'fgsandford1000',password:'sanford1000',message:'check me out'});

},
 cancel:function()
 {

},
 error:function(error)
 {
 },
 allowImageEditing:true,
});

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this issue as well. The same code worked well with 0.8.x. I've created a [request](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/15381/openphotogallery-doesnt-work-in-new-windows) on Appcelerator's Q&A section since their team may not check here often.